# Why doesn't skiplist in leveldb require lock for GET operation?

Tags: concurrency, atomic, leveldb, memory-barriers

These are the pseudo code for skiplist::insert():

```
 node = new Node();
 prev = find_place_to_insert();
 node->next = prev->next;
 memory_barrier();
 prev->next = node;
```

There is no lock (both in function insert() and external calls) while writing to skiplist (`prev->next = node`) . So why it's safe to read in one thread while writing in another?

There's another implemention which uses `std::atomic` for the `Node::next` field. Why the memory barrier version doesn't need to use an atomic variable?

（It is talking about reader-writer race, not writer-writer race.）

Comment: Version with std::atomic is in db/skiplist.h, but where is the memory barrier version?

Comment: @AlexandrKonovalov leveldb/port/atomic_pointer.h has some version of AtomicPointer which is used in skiplist. I'm reading <<C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading>> and maybe i'll find the answer in the book.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So your question might be rephrased as "why an acquire/release pair is equivalent to MemoryBarrier", so to say.